# Обособление оборота "не тратя слишком много времени"

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика, деепричастный-оборот

Вопрос вроде бы простой и сиюминутный, но что-то засомневался.

***Не тратя слишком много времени*** — это всегда деепричастный оборот и всегда обособляется?

Контекст полностью приводить не вижу смысла, мне как раз и интересен вариант, если есть, который позволяет не обособлять.
У меня было *"мне это надо для того, чтобы [сделать "первое дело"], [сделать "второе дело"], [cделать "третье дело"], не тратя слишком много времени"*. При этом "не тратя..." должно относиться только к последнему, а при обособлении этого не видно.

Comment: Не будет разночтений, если "не тратя слишком много времени" с союзом И поставить перед  [cделать "третье дело"]. Мне это надо для того, чтобы [сделать "первое дело"], [сделать "второе дело"] и, не тратя слишком много времени, [cделать "третье дело"]

Comment: @М_Г, да, спасибо, я это видел, но мне  и этот вариант хочется написать без обособления, вот в чем штука. Поэтому я и поставил вопрос ребром, есть ли вообще ситуации, когда не обособлять допустимо.

Comment: Но ведь наречием заменить нельзя без изменения смысла, значит, деепричастный оборот и обособляется всегда.

Comment: @Людмила, но это опять наш старый разговор о разнице критерия и признака. Возможность замены на наречие - это  признак, признак не абсолютный, не являющийся критерием. К  тому же есть наречие "оперативно", которое пусть и с оговорками на разговорный характер, имеет очень близкий смысл. Т. е. потенциально вполне может существовать такая замена.

Answer (score 1):

Оборот этот **обособляется практически всегда** (скорее всего, в силу своей распространенности).

Как вариант, **можно использовать однородный ряд**, в котором первое наречие будет необособленным.

**Например:** [cделать "третье дело"] без лишних разговоров (= без задержки, незамедлительно, в один момент, сразу же и т.д.) , не тратя слишком много времени.

Comment: Практически - или всегда?

Comment: Мне такие примеры не встречались, да и трудно их даже придумать. Хотя это устойчивое выражение, но оно свободного состава  (слова можно менять, переставлять), приобрести значение обстоятельства  для него сложно.  А вот, к примеру, сходное по значению одиночное деепричастие "не откладывая"  может не обособляться в качестве обстоятельства : "Но тут за окном запела пеночка так чисто и юно, что он решил ехать не откладывая, прямо сейчас". "Тогда вам тем более нужно не откладывая познакомиться с человеком, с которым меня недавно свели".

Comment: *приобрести значение обстоятельства для него сложно* - вот это уже по существу. Но я-то как раз и задумался над тем, может ли это быть обстоятельством. И не вижу причин, почему бы и нет. Отсюда и возник вопрос. Внутренне я готов счесть весь оборот обстоятельством.

Comment: У нас много фразеологизмов на основе деепричастия, состоящих из двух слов, которые не обособляются как обстоятельства (скрепя сердце, не переводя духа и т.д), но вот фразеологизм из трех слов "положа руку на сердце" уже обособляется. Значит, объем выражения очень важен, распространенный  оборот просто не вписывается в структуру простого предложения так, чтобы мы могли бы произнести его без пауз, не обособляя. Поэтому он будет вести себя именно как обособленная структура, здесь даже не важно, каково его семантическое наполнение. Соответственно, он  и  не встречаются без обособления.

Answer (score 1):

Во всех (найденных мною) предложениях, где употребляется "не тратя слишком много времени", оборот обособляется:
*...как добавить функции (например, загрузку документа) в уже существующее приложение **, не тратя слишком много времени.***

В предложениях с оборотами, ***которые  синонимичны и немного короче***, также присутствует обособление:

*Царь велит своим боярам,

**Времени не тратя даром,**

И царицу и приплод

Тайно бросить в бездну вод.*

*Как добиваться от авторов качества, **не тратя много времени**?*
*Лион, **не тратя даром времени**, принялся закреплять ноги, привязывая травяные жгуты к проделанным во льду «ушкам».*

Нашлось одно, на мой взгляд, спорное (с точки зрения пунктуации) предложение с "укороченным" оборотом, где он не выделен:
*Как идти к мечте **не тратя много времени**.*

Я бы и в этом предложении поставила запятую (согласно правилам).
Думаю, что оборот "не тратя слишком много времени" обособляется всегда. Не нашла я причин, ситуаций или предложений, где бы выделение устойчивого выражения  не требовалось.
Буду рада, если меня кто-нибудь разубедит.